# Integrating Nutch and Solr

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

All, I am trying to integrate `Nutch` and `Solr` working together by following [this guide](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)

Nutch version is 1.1
Solr version is 5.3.1

When I tried to index the Nutch crawl result into the soly by running following command in the cygwin.

`bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/`

The command line is running without any exception. 
But When I tried to run query in the Solr admin . Nothing can be searched .

[image]

I wondered if there is anything exception happened when index into Solr.
But I checked the log of Solr . Nothing happened. Anything I missed?

Comment: look for errors in your Nutch log files (I think it's called hadoop.log).

Answer (score 0):

Your Solr URL should include the name of the core as well:

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/gettingstarted_shard1_replica1/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/
```